# How can I recreate Ruby's sort_by {rand} in python?

Tags: python

I have a line of code where can sort an array into random order:

`someArray.sort_by {rand}`

so in python, how can I convert to it to python code?

Comment: `some_array.shuffle` would be more idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: You shouldn't even do this in Ruby (and why bother, when there's `someArray.sort`?). `someArray.sort_by {rand}` is a _horrible_ way to sort, which doesn't actually even yield fully uniform shuffled outputs. See https://thethirdone.github.io/blog/posts/random-sorting/

Comment: @Alexander: While `sort_by {rand}` is bad, it's not quite as bad as in your link. In `sort_by {rand}`, `rand` is a key function, not a comparator; every element of the array is assigned a random number (computed once per element, not once per comparison), then the elements are sorted according to those random numbers. It's not generating random comparison results. While this is still a bad way to shuffle an array, it's not as ridiculously awful as the random comparator example in your link.

Comment: @user2357112 Ahhh yes, great callout. So I take that back, it's not fundamentally broken, it's just odd and unecessary, given the existence of `#shuffle`/`#shuffle!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
import random
l = [1, 2, 3]
# l is shuffled in place
random.shuffle(l)
# Print to see the shuffled l
print(l)
```

Comment: using the above snippet code and passing a list like this `my_list = ["2",
           "0",
           "2",
           "2",
           "-",
           "1",
           "2",
           "-",
           "1",
           "5",
           " ",
           "2",
           "1",
           ":",
           "2",
           "2",
           ":",
           "4",
           "3",
           " ",
           "+",
           "0",
           "3",
           "0",
           "0"]`  `print(random.shuffle(my_list))` returns `none`

Comment: @hanan it returns `None` but the array does change. try printing the array again after the `shuffle`

Comment: @jvx8ss it worked thanks, but this also inherits security issues in {rand} in ruby as well in python random?

Comment: @hanan I don't know about that sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this by:

```
import random
array = [1, 2, 3]

print(array) #now nothing is changed because shuffle was not applied
random.shuffle(array)
print(array) #then now array is randomized.
```

hope it helps.